# No Scoreboard (how do I fix?)

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I’m making a Kit PvP and I decide to add a scoreboard. A few minutes later, an admin joins and removes the scoreboard. I then kick the admin that removed the scoreboard and added the scoreboard back. The game said it added the scoreboard but nothing is on the right side of the screen.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things that can be causing this:

1. You didn't run the command to make it show on the side:

   ```
   /scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar <objectiveName>
   ```
2. There are no values on the scoreboard, making it hidden, even if the setdisplay command was ran:

   ```
   /scoreboard players set @p <objectiveName> 1
   ```

   to set your score to 1 and make it show.

Comment: The first one worked but the second didn’t. But either way Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean, the first one didn't solve the problem?

Comment: no he means the second one didnt but the first one did

Comment: @Daemoncito09 I understand you might notve been able to because of the cooldown, but if this worked for you please accept it now by clicking the grey checkmark! This shows other uses that this solution worked and gives Bruno Rodrigues reputation.